# Symbol y couldn't be resolved

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, graph

I have a problem with a C++ problem, it says that y it's not resolved and I don't understand why... The error is in the dist function and i don't understand what it is not correct... Any ideas what can I do? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

    struct Points
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        char name[4];
    };
  float dist(Points p)
  {   return std::sqrt(p.x*p.x+p.y*p*y);
  }

int main(){
    float x,y;
    Points pt[4];
    int n=0;
        while (cin >> pt[n].name >> pt[n].x >> pt[n].y)
                 { n++;
                  if (n==5) break;

                 }
     bool execute = true;
    while (execute) {
        execute = false;
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            if (dist(pt[i]) > dist(pt[i+1])) {

                Points temp = pt[i];
                 pt[i] = pt[i+1];
                  pt[i+1] = temp;
                execute = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo `p*y` --> `p.y`. In the future try to add some generous spacing between certain operators (such as multiplication) and operands. Makes such blunders easier to spot.

Comment: Do you want replace `p*y` with `p.y`?

Comment: A generous helping of proper formatting is in order.

Comment: Sorry but you're using the distance formula for just one point?

Comment: @codekaizer No problem with that; it gives the point's distance from origin.

Comment: @Angew, you're right. got blurred for a moment due to `Point*s*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspeled, need dot(.) here `p.x*p.x+p.y*p*y` => `p.x*p.x+p.y*p.y`

```
float dist(Points p)
{   
    return std::sqrt(p.x*p.x+p.y*p.y);
}
```